# Soap Web Service migration from tomcat to Jboss 4.2.3

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jboss

I have web service which is using JAXB as marshaller. When i was deplaying it on Tomcat server everything was ok, parsing, sending response - all good. When i changed to Jboss 4.2.3 i got following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jboss.ws.core.soap.TextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Comment
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker.startNode(TreeWalker.java:287) ~[na:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.xml.serializer.TreeWalker.traverse(TreeWalker.java:143) ~[na:2.7.0]
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:389) ~[na:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.AbstractLoggingInterceptor.logMessageSource(AbstractLoggingInterceptor.java:149) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.AbstractLoggingInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractLoggingInterceptor.java:89) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.handleRequest(DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.java:78) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:224) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:221) [spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) [spring-webmvc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710) [servlet-api.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803) [servlet-api.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96) [tmp124843923712011984jbossweb-service.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182) [tmp124843923712011984jbossweb-service.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84) [tmp124843923712011984jbossweb-service.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157) [tmp124843923712011984jbossweb-service.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446) [tmp1688167291209800062jbossweb.jar:4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA date=200807181439)]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_09]
```

**Source Endpoint**

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "chain", namespace = "http://jakisadres.com/caservice")
    @ResponsePayload
    public ChainResponse getChain(@RequestPayload Chain param) {

        ChainResponse response = new ChainResponse();
        response.setChainResult("cos");
        return response;
    }
```

**DispatcherServlet**

```
<sws:annotation-driven/>

    <context:annotation-config  />

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping">
        <description>An endpoint mapping strategy that looks for @Endpoint and @PayloadRoot annotations.</description>
    </bean>

    <sws:interceptors>
        <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor"/>
    </sws:interceptors>


    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
            <property name="contextPath" value="pl.signet.famoc.ws.jaxb.marshaller" /> 
    </bean>
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter"
            p:messageFactory-ref="messageFactory"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter"/>
```

any clue what am i missing?

Comment: Add some source related to your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i got answer, problem lies in `Classloader` of JBOSS. Implementation of server contains some of the classes which are used before my project dependencies, thats why JBOSS use default parser insteed of `javax.xml.bind` to parse JAXB.